# Multi-Facing Tree Layout and Reformatting JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, tree

I'm working on a tree layout like this one: http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-tree/ that is based off mbostock's original design (http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html).

I'm having 3 issues with it. I'd like to be able to extend the branches both left and right of the root - in other words I'd like to be able to mirror what the sample looks like.

The second issue I'm having is that the flare.json file for this format needs to be in a very specific format - it needs to look exactly like this

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": [
        {},
        {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

While mine looks approximately like

```
"head": {
    "title": "titleHere",
    "ownerName": "nameHere
},
"body": {
    "outline": [
        {
            "outline": [
                {
                    "_text": "A"
                },
                {
                    "_text": "B"
                },
                {
                    "_text": "C"
                },
                {
                    "_text": "D"
                },
                {
                    "_text": "E"
                }
            ],
            "_text": "Category Header"
        },
        {


},
}
```

I basically need to write an algorithm that re-formats what I have into the correct format so I can feed it into my tree layout, if that makes sense.

The final issue I'd like to work on is to be able to edit the text by double-clicking on the tree chart.

Comment: And where are the codes of your attempts?

Comment: I'm trying to adapt the following tree layout design to fit my needs - I don't have any experience with this so I'm really just looking for a place to start and I can go from there. http://www.robschmuecker.com/d3-js-drag-and-drop-zoomable-tree/ (code)